# ENV ["RAILS_MASTER_KEY"] works for master.key, but what environment variable will rails check for development.key or production.key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, environment-variables, credentials

I have been trying to put my rails credential keys into a environment variable.  The Rails Guide says:

Rails uses config/master.key or alternatively looks for the environment variable "RAILS_MASTER_KEY" to encrypt the credentials file.

I'm running Rails 7, and I have a different credentials file for each Rails environment, i.e.

config/credentials/

```
development.yml.enc
development.key
production.yml.enc
production.key
```

So it says I can use "RAILS_MASTER_KEY"] to override any of these .key files.  I'm trying to figure out a way to use an environment variable like "RAILS_DEV_KEY" in place of development.key, for instance.

When I run this:

Rails.application.credentials

I get this:

[image: Rails.application.credentials output]

Is there a way to change the "@env_key" variable above to say "RAILS_DEV_KEY"

Comment: You use the same environment variable `RAILS_MASTER_KEY` and pass the appropriate master key.
on development env pass the value in `development.key` while on `production` pass the `production.key`